# Symfony 2.7 - Render a template and then redirect to another page

Tags: php, symfony, redirect, symfony-2.7

Is it possible in Symfony 2.7 to render a template and after a number of second, redirect a `User` to another page?

Comment: You mean, delay the template rendering?

Comment: @PraveenKumar No, I mean render a template and then redirect the user to another page directly.

Comment: You mean show them a page for x seconds then redirect? If so, use JS, or HTML meta. Nothing to do with Symfony / PHP by the time you're rendered to screen.

Comment: Use a JavaScript man, client side `setTimeout()`.

Comment: @JonStirling Yes, I mean show a page for x second and then, redirect them to for example to the main page of the app

Comment: @ZugZwang See the first two answers. `:D`

Comment: @PraveenKumar my doubt was if there was a way to do that directly with symfony

Comment: @ZugZwang That's very primitive.

Comment: @PraveenKumar Thanks!